# Unable to access files but directory listing works in MS IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have hosted a website on http with directory listing enabled in MS IIS V 6.1 on windows server 2008. on port 8080 without ssl. I am able to access and list the directories using both localhost and IP. But accessing any file gets me empty response , response header is mentioned below.

Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 13 Jan 2018 19:27:48 GMT 
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Any help/suggestion appreciated.

Comment: "But accessing file does not succeed." - Unfortunately, this strikes me as a bit unclear. I might suggest you edit the question to include the specific type(s) of file(s) that fail and the details of the failure (what are you doing to access the files, specifically happens when the error occurs, etc).

Comment: updated. Please let me know if anymore info required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1233864.aspx?IIS+sending+empty+file+for+Script+file+requests+instead+of+the+file

The issue was due to missing module static content

> The first possibility is that you missed to install the static content feature in IIS. To resolve this problem, you could try to install the feature in control panel->programs->turn windows features on and off->Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Common HTTP Features/Static Content.

Comment: Consider making this answer better for the site and others by quoting the parts of the answer from the link you provided in case it ever goes bad the other detail (other than just a link) will still be available here to help others. It seems there are a couple answers on that post for various methods so it sounds like you just added that section to the config file along with specific mime types of the same as that post or what exactly?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for your suggestion. Added the quoted text from the link. I had issue with a module viz "Static Content" which was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Per your answer, the solution (as mentioned) seems to be that the Static Content module for IIS was disabled.

To turn the Static Content module on:

- Open the Control Panel, then select *Programs and Features*.
- Choose *Turn Windows features on or off*.
- Under the *Internet Information Services* subtree, mark *World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content*.